# Back up GitLab manually

Tags: backup, gitlab

When I run `gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create` I have this issue
`database locale is incompatible with operating system`

How can I manually back up gitlab repositories and database?

I backed up

```
/opt/gitlab
/etc/gitlab
/var/opt/gitlab
```

so far.

Are there other directories that I should back up?

My repositories are in `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data`.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636653/connect-to-postgresql-database-with-different-locale help you?

Comment: I have a messed up VPS and nothing really works due to a broken upgrade. I can't even install anything due to broken dependencies :D and I don't have the `localedef` command installed for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find the [documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md) about this Rake task useful as you troubleshoot this.

If you can't overcome the database locale problem, you could try skipping the database backup with:

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create SKIP=db
```

But should try to find an alternative way to back up the database.  I infer from the error message that the database is Postgres, so [`pg_dumpall`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html) might do what you want:

```
pg_dumpall > gitlab.sql
```

Otherwise you could try doing a [File System Level Backup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-file.html) of the [Postgres directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137060/where-does-postgresql-store-the-database), and try restoring it on a new server with the same version.

Comment: I tried the 1st command but got the same error when dumping `repositories`. I'm gonna install GitLab locally on my deb9 and see if my manual backups are enough.

Comment: You could try SKIP'ing more stages as well, but maybe they all depend on being able to read the database.  You may have to do a manual Postgres backup along with your other folders - I've added a link for that.

Comment: I will install the same gitlab-ce version and manually import the folders I backed up. Thank you for your response

Comment: It worked well for me by installing the same version and manually importing, i'll post a new response, maybe someone will find it useful

Answer (score 1):

Manually backing up and restoring worked well for me
First I checked the current gitlab version
`cd /opt/gitlab/ && cat version-manifest.txt`

Then I checked the `gitlab-ce` version
`gitlab-ctl               8.16.2`

I downloaded the same version from [here](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/trusty/gitlab-ce_8.16.2-ce.0_amd64.deb) (replace 8.16.2 with your version or search [here](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce))

After downloading the deb file using `wget`, I installed it like this

```
dpkg -i gitlab-ce_8.16.2-ce.0_amd64.deb
```

After that I imported the files from my old vps using rsync

```
rsync -chavzP --stats root@myvps.net:/var/opt/gitlab/ /var/opt/gitlab/
rsync -chavzP --stats root@myvps.net:/etc/gitlab/ /etc/gitlab/
```

Then I restarted gitlab

```
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

And all was back in order

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got it working.  Did you have any existing user profiles, issue trackers, etc?  I would have expected them to be lost in the move.

Comment: Yeah all the data was inside the `/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data` i think.
So `/etc/gitlab/` has the config and `/var/opt/gitlab/` contains the data

Comment: Ah right.  I see a discussion (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1963) about moving the folder, which confirms that.  (It also suggests running `gitlab-ctl` stop first.  Hopefully your instance wasn't running, but it wouldn't have hurt anyway :) .. Out of interest, can you get the rake backup task working now?

Comment: That's would have been helpful too. Lucky for me the permissions were conserved thanks to the `a` flag in `-chavzP` as per https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+-chavzP+--stats+root%40myvps.net%3A%2Fvar%2Fopt%2Fgitlab%2F+%2Fvar%2Fopt%2Fgitlab%2F . Also the backup works fine now, I guess I will accept your answer as it's more straight forward than my manual approach